# How to create a static variable from a state variable made with useState hook on ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am trying to get the value of a useState hook variable without having that new variable hooked when the useState variable updates ( avoiding newVariable value update when stateVariable value changes ).

For example, I have two components, App and Edit.

App.js

```
...
import Edit from './edit'
...
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ name: "", password: "" });
  ...
   return(
  ...
    <Route path="/edit">
     <Edit
       socketConnected={socketConnected}
       socket={socket}
       user={user}
       setUser={setUser}
     ></Edit>
    </Route>
  ...
   );
}
```

Edit.js

```
function Edit(props) {
    const [user, setUser] = [props.user, props.setUser];
    const previousName = user.name; // Check this out.
    ...
    return (
     <label>Your previous name was: {previousName}</label>
     <input value={user.name} onChange={(e) => { setUser({ ...user, name: e.target.value }) }}></input>
    );
}
```

This way i should be able to change live the variable `user`, and have `previousName`  stay the same, so that the user can see its previous name without updating.

Well, I've tried the following when assigning `user.name`'s value to `previousUser`:

- `const previousName = user.name;`
- `const previousName = user.name.toString();`
- `const previousName = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user.name));`
- `let userCloned = Object.assign({}, user); const previousName = userCloned.name;`
- `let userCloned = { ...user }; const previousName = userCloned.name;`
- `let userCloned = { ...user }; const previousName = userCloned.name; Object.freeze(previousName);`

I have no clue how to do it, since no matter how I assign the state values to a normal variable, it STILL gets liked to the setUser hook, even after JSON parsing, which is driving me insane, and I am running out of ideas.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is the best usecase of useRef because, useRef will keep a hold of
> the first instance/data that it will ever get and will never change it
> through out the life-cycle of the app unless been manually updated(ref.current).

```
 const [user, setUser] = useState({ name: "", password: "" });
 const prevUsername = useRef(user.name);
```

> Nota bene: if you also want to get hold of the previous prop just like
> componentDidUpdate previusProps before doing some update, also note that; if `setUser` gets `dispatched` with new data, you need to update the `prevUsername ref/variable`. You can do that like this:

```
setUser((prevUser)=>{ 
 //here you get the previous user before updating
 prevUsername.current = prevUser.name;
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood you basically want to copy `user.name` prop to some variable such that future updates to `props.user.name` are ignored by that variable. In such case you must copy that props to a state variable:

```
 // inside Edit   
 const [previousName, setPreviousName] = useState(props.user.name);
```

This way `previousName` will get initialized with `props.user.name` when that component mounts for the first time. Further updates to `props.user.name` will be ignored by this state variable.

Only if you unmount the `Edit` component and mount again, then it will copy the `props.user.name` again into `previousName`.

PS Alternatively you can use `useRef` instead of `useState` in my example